# solve linear system Ax=b, when A is m.n matrix where m<n.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=[a_{ij}]_{m\times n}$ where $m<n$ and $a_{ij}$ are some functions of parameter $t$. I would like to solve $Ax=b$. For example $A=[a_{ij}]_{2\times 10}$ and it cannot be simplified more. Now I want to determine $x=Gb$ where $G$ is a suitable matrix that give the solution. In general, finding $G$ as a generalized inverse of matrix $A$ such that $AGA=A$ is not easy.
Is there any idea to determine all the solutions of this system.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$Let the columns of $N$ be a basis for the nullspace of $A$, so that $AN=0$. Then the solution set of $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ is given by $\vec{x}=\vec{x}_0+N\vec{c}$, where $\vec{x}_0$ is any vector that satisfies $A\vec{x}_0=\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ is any appropriately sized vector such that the matrix product is defined.

$N$ can be computed a number of ways. The easiest (but not necessarily most numerically efficient) method to compute this matrix on a computer is using an [SVD decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ has rank $< m$, there may be no solutions, depending on $b$.
Assuming $A$ has rank $m$, $A A^T$ is invertible and you can take
$G = A^T (A A^T)^{-1}$.